# Duplicating a table in Firebird

Tags: firebird

I'm currently writing a (C++)program that reads csv files into a Firebird database. During the algorithm, my tables are modified.
Since the whole reading process takes a few minutes, I've made the reading part optional, thus if the database is already filled with data, the user can decide not to update it.

When running the program more than once, I want to use the original data, instead of the data that has been modified during the last run, so I thought of doing something like

> create table table1_backup as (select*from table1);

and then, when restarting the program (in case we do not want to update the data)

> delete table table1;
>   create table table1 as (select*from table1_backup);

Seemingly, duplicating tables in Firebird doesn't work this way.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you need to persist data in the new table between program runs? Or do you ALWAYS clear it? Can different programs together work with that new table or only one program can exclusively use it? It seems you do not need to create tables, only to load data to be totally removed on disconnection. That is GTT - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/global-temp-tables/info

Comment: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq217/

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a table from another table in Firebird. See also [Does Firebird support creating tables using SELECT statement?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq217/).

As suggested by [Arioch 'The](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976391/arioch-the) in the comments, you might be looking for [global temporary tables](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-gtt) instead. Global temporary tables have persistent DDL, but data is only visible to a single transaction (`on commit delete rows`) or only to the connection that inserted the data (`on commit preserve rows`).

You could use a temporary table as a staging area before making permanent changes to your database.